# Nextcloud Collaborative Tags in Group Folders

Tags: nextcloud

NextCloud 12.0.4
Files automated tagging 1.2.2
Group Folders 1.2.0

I have a well running NC 12 installation with (more than) the above listed apps. But when I upload files to a shared folder, they do not get tagged. If I upload them to some other users folder, they do get tagged.

I tested upload via webinterface and via desktop client, both have the same result.

Are collaborative tags possible in group folders? [This](https://github.com/nextcloud/files_retention/issues/38) closed issue in the related app files_retention somehow sounds like it should work? [Same issue here](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/files-automated-tagging-not-working-on-group-folders/26774?u=chrisgi)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I have no rep. Long time listener first time caller...

This is a known issue: https://github.com/nextcloud/files_automatedtagging/issues/46